# Passing LDAP Credentials to httpRequest Step in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ldap, jenkins-pipeline

I what to make a httpRequest via pipeline with LDAP Credentials of pipeline triggering user.
LDAP Credentials need to be passed as 'authentication' property in httpRequest Step in pipeline.

```
  pipeline {
      agent any 
      stages{
        stage('Remote Call'){
            httpRequest url : <RemoteUrl> , authentication : 'LDAP_Credentails'
        }
      }
     }
```

Suppose user with LDAP Credentials, say

- LdapUsername :  deerajk
- LdapPasssword : dummyPassword

*Note :Above mentioned Credentails are not not part of Jenkins Credential Store*

Logs in to Jenkins with above mentioned Credentials and triggers a pipeline job , Say pipeline name 'MakeHttpRequestPipeline'. Mentioned  pipeline makes an httpRequest call to which needs to use above mentioned Credentials in authentication property of httpRequest Step. This httpRequest is used to get token of LDAP user from Remote Jenkins and Trigger a job on Remote Jenkins.

What did i try ?
I could get user name how Triggered Job by following Code

```
    def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_BASE_NAME, Job.class)
    def build = job.getBuildByNumber(env.BUILD_ID as int)
    def userId = build.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId()
```

I want to do the following

```
 - Get LDAP Credentials reference id of user how triggers pipeline
 - Pass the LDAP Credentials reference id in httpRequest Made by Pipeline
```

Let me know if their is a way to do so.

Comment: If your LDAP credentials are not part of the credentials binding, then they probably need to be passed in the `custom_headers` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Get user Credentials via following parameters :

```
parameters{
    credentials(credentialType: 'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl',
            defaultValue: '', description: 'Select your LDAP from Drop Down if avaliable else Create it',
            name: 'deployCredentialsId', required: true)
}
```

Use Credentials as follows :

```
stages{
    stage('TRIGGER PIPELINE'){
        steps{
            withCredentials([usernameColonPassword( credentialsId: '${deployCredentialsId}' , variable: 'DEPLOY_KEY')]){
                script{
                 def creds = "$DEPLOY_KEY"
                 String auth = creds.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()  
                 def response = httpRequest customHeaders: [ [maskValue: false, name: 'Authorization', value: "Basic ${auth}"], [maskValue: false, name: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/json'],] , 
                 url : 'https://{jenkinsHost}/me/configure' , ignoreSslErrors: true 
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Sending Custom Headers works